# Can we use http.sys to run application on linux container?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, docker, linux-containers

The reason for asking this is , my application has .net framework with Aspnet core2.2 and runs using dotnet run. It also uses windows authentication.

I want to know if this application can be self contained and run on a Linux container.

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot. HTTP.sys only runs on Windows.

Source: [HttpSys, learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys)